# Gradle dependency substitution with local file dev environment

Tags: gradle, build

I am working on a project using gradle with multiple subprojects. In the root build.gradle, we declare some dependencies. Most of these are standard dependencies, but several of them are specific to our project and only accessible from our GitLab environment. This is roughly what our build.gradle looks like:

```
subprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'

    compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

    dependencies {

        compileOnly "GroupName:ModuleA:${rootProject.ext.moduleAVersion}"
        compileOnly "GroupName:ModuleB:${rootProject.ext.moduleBVersion}"
        testCompile "GroupName:ModuleA:${rootProject.ext.moduleAVersion}"

        ...other non-problematic deps...

    }

    tasks.withType(Ear) {

        dependencies {

            earlib "GroupName:ModuleA:${rootProject.ext.moduleAVersion}"
            ...other non-problematic deps...
        }

        ear {
            baseName "some valid name"

        }
    }
}
```

In development, we comment out the the "compileOnly" and "testCompile" for the revelant deps, and instead replace them with logic like this:

```
def sdkJars = fileTree(dir: "${rootProject.rootDir}\\BuildFiles")
compileOnly sdkJars
testCompile sdkJars
```

The sdkJars is a valid directory that contains all of the jar files needed to satisfy those dependencies. This can be incredibly unwieldy having to constantly insert this logic and ensure it doesn't get committed when pushing changes, and is always a hassle when switching to new branches. We need a new paradigm that will allow developers to simply build with the "env" set to "dev" and not have to worry about modifying their gradle files.

Is it possible to use dependency substitution or something similar to manually load the dependencies from jar files when in the dev environment. In testing I explored options like this but couldn't figure out how to replace the dependency with a jar from a file:

```
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution.all { DependencySubstitution dependency ->
        // In dev env, replace deps we know will fail
        if (project.env == "dev") {
            if (dependency.requested instanceof ModuleComponentSelector && dependency.requested.group == "GroupName") {
                  // what can go here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Learning is fun!

Since posting this question I learned about the simple and straightforward solution to this problem: Flat Directory repositories.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sec:declaring_multiple_repositories

In my repositories, I added:

```
            flatDir {
                dirs rootProject.property("devBuildFiles")
            }
```

This allows developers to specify a directory in either the project level, or user level, gradle.properties file (https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home).

Gradle will then treat the specified directory as a repository. It will match any module name against files in the directory.

Example:

original dependency declaration:

```
compileOnly GroupName:ModuleA:${rootProject.ext.moduleAVersion}
```

evaluates to:

```
GroupName:ModuleA:1.0.0
```

which can be satisfied by a jar file named:

```
"ModuleA-1.0.0.jar"
```